# Can you specify a nested key for a table in KSQL?

Tags: ksqldb

I'm trying to create a table from a topic with an object key, but KSQL didn't recognize the variable.

Any solution for this?

```
create table csvexporttable (HEADER STRUCT<BusinessDate varchar>,
                             body STRUCT<ActiveStore_SalesTransaction_170 STRUCT<ThirdPartyLoyaltyData STRUCT<TotalAdvantage STRUCT<AdvantageAmount int>,CustomerNo varchar>,TransactionDetail ARRAY <STRUCT<TransactionDetailGroup STRUCT<item STRUCT<ManualPrice int,PriceOverride int>>,DetailFlagVoid int>>,SuspendFlag int,Total Array<STRUCT<TotalAmount DOUBLE>>>>) 
with (KAFKA_TOPIC='************',
      VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
      KEY='HEADER->BusinessDate');
```

Answer (score 1):

Structured keys are not yet supported by KSQL.  You can upvote (+1) the feature request at https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/824.